# ¿Cómo recupero archivos que se borraron al hacer un push rebase en Git?

Tags: java, git, git-push

espero por favor me ayuden. Tenía un proyecto en NetBeans el cual quise colocarlo en un repositorio en BitBucket, el problema es que yo hice un commit y luego hice un rebase push, ahora todos los archivos que tenía en mi carpeta local, es decir los .java, ya no están. Ojalá me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Estaban esos .java bajo control de versiones? En ese caso no te apures porque aún estarán en algún _commit_ anterior al que puedes volver. Incluso si el commit en que estaban ha desaparecido debido a un rebase, todavía puedes verlo con `git reflog`. Para detalles más concretos necesitaría una pregunta más concreta, con detalles como en qué commits tenías los java bajo control, qué hiciste después, cuándo hiciste el rebase, contra qué rama, cómo hiciste luego el push (usaste `--force-`? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Traducción de la [respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/8933039) por [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey)

El camino más fácil sería de encontrar cuál era la `HEAD` de la rama inmediatamente antes del comando `rebase`, para lo que podemos mirar el [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) ...

```
git reflog
```

y restablecer la rama actual a ese estado (con la advertencia habitual de estar absolutamente seguro antes de usar `reset` con la opción `--hard`).

Supongamos que el *commit* anterior era `HEAD@{5}` en el *reflog*, entonces:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{5}
```

En Windows, es posible que debas usar comillas alrededor de la referencia:

```
git reset --hard "HEAD@{5}"
```

Puedes antes verificar el historial del antiguo `HEAD` candidato simplemente haciendo un `git log HEAD@{5}` (Windows: `git log "HEAD@{5}"`).

Si no has desactivado la opción de tener *reflogs* por rama, deberías poder hacer simplemente, `git reflog branchname@{1}` ya que una operación *rebase* separa la cabeza de rama antes de volver a colocarla en la cabeza final. Comprueba bien esto, ya que yo no lo he verificado desde hace tiempo.

Por defecto, todos los reflogs están activados para repositorios *no-bare*:

```
[core]
    logAllRefUpdates = true
```

## Otra información adicional: (traducido de  [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git/34777222#34777222))

**Lo primero ¿qué es `HEAD`?**

`HEAD` es simplemente una referencia al *commit* actual (más reciente) en la rama actual.  Solo puede haber 1 `HEAD` en cualquier momento dado.

Si no está en el último *commit*, lo que significa que `HEAD` apunta aun *commit* previo en la historia, se llama *detached HEAD* (`HEAD` desconectado).

[image]

Algunas opciones:

**`git checkout`**

```
git checkout <commit_id>
```

**`git reflog`**

Siempre puedes usar el `reflog` también

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

Esto te devolverá a tu commit deseado

[image]

---

#### `git reset HEAD --hard <commit_id>`

"Mueve" la cabeza al *commit* deseado.

```sh
# Esto destruirá cualquier modificación local.
# No lo haga si tiene un trabajo no guardado que desea mantener.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternativamente, si hay trabajo para conservar:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# Esto guarda las modificaciones, luego vuelve a aplicar ese parche después del reset.
# Podría obtener conflictos de _merge_, si ha modificado cosas que 
# habían cambiado desde el commit a que volvió con reset.
```

- Nota: ( [Desde Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt) )
  también puede usar el `git rebase --no-autostash`.

---

#### `git checkout`

```
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X //x es la cantidad de commits que retrocede
```

Esto creará una nueva rama apuntando al commit deseado

---

Aquí hay un esquema general de lo que se puede hacer.

[image]

> Aquí está la [Respuesta Original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777222/8933039)

Comment: Muchas gracias! soy nuevo en esto de Git y con el comando `git reflog` se mostro el primer commit que hice con el rebase

Comment: @Cristopher me alegra haber ayudado.